# Postgres: INSERT the results of a SELECT query that has a WITH statement

Tags: postgresql

In a PostgreSQL 9.5 database I have objects of different types (each stored in its own table) which are interrelated in a DAG.  To represent this DAG I have set up `node` and `edge` tables.  The `node` table simply stores a globally unique id, which will be shared by all the tables storing objects:

```
CREATE TABLE node (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);
```

Let’s say one of my object types is in table `library`.  Ignoring other fields, this table is simply:

```
CREATE TABLE library (
  uuid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES node(id),
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
)
```

I can load a single entry with id `XXX` into `library` as follows:

```
WITH x AS (
  INSERT INTO node (id) VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO library (id, uuid) VALUES ('XXX', (SELECT id FROM x));
```

However, I have a view `import.library` that references an external resource, and I want to load `public.library` *en masse* from that view.  In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO library (uuid, id)
  WITH x AS (
    INSERT INTO node (id) VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING id
  )
  SELECT (SELECT id FROM x), id FROM import.library;
```

That is not possible, since a data-modifying `WITH` statement has to be at the top level.

I can achieve the same result by using an anonymous function in a `DO` statement:

```
DO $$DECLARE l_id TEXT;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN SELECT id FROM import.library
  LOOP
    WITH x AS (
      INSERT INTO node (id) VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING id
    )
    INSERT INTO library (id, uuid) VALUES (l_id, (SELECT id FROM x));
  END LOOP;
END$$;
```

This works, but I would still like to know whether it’s possible to do the same in a simple SQL statement without resorting to an anonymous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the uuid in the `node` table is generated by a sequence, the only way I can think of is to flip the order of insertion:

```
WITH x AS (
  INSERT INTO library (uuid, id)
  SELECT nextval('node_id_seq'), id 
  FROM import_library
  returning uuid  
)
INSERT INTO node (id) 
select uuid
from x
```

Comment: That’s really thinking outside the box!  Yup, that seems to do the trick, so I’m going to hit ‘Accept’ on that…  Thanks!